# Why the colors in the game view are pink and not like in the scene view?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What i want to create is kind of evening/night situation.
The in the game view the player trees the bottom of the lamp are in pink.

In the Main Camera i checked the hdr (it's now true).
Also in the main camera i added the Color Correction Curves (script)

Then i have two Directional light on more on the right one more on the left near the lamp.
Also the sky seems to be too much with light it's not really night or evening.

[image: Colors]

Screenshot of the Directional light settings:

[image: Directional light]

And the Directional light (1)

[image: Directional light 1]

What i'm trying to do is this tutorial but i can't make a good night scene like in the tutorial:

[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36ruPSD7FJk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change fog color:
Window -> Lighting -> Scene -> Fog -> Fog Color

i believe that is this, to sky you need change the skybox for a material more dark in the same window:

Window -> Lighting -> Scene -> Environment -> Skybox Material

I hope this is it!
Sorry my bad english i'm learning.